# Pentaho Kettle JSON Output

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-design-studio

I have to design a KTR, where am passing fields from a step - Select values to JSON Output Step. The output from it is as shown in figure before:
[image]

How Can i remove the fields Chart, Title , XAxis, YAxis, series? So that i get only result from this step as outputvalue

My KTR is: [image]

Answer (score 0):

At select values step 4.2.2 select those fields which are required, in your case output field only.

for that press on get fields and delete the fields you mansion.

i am not sure with json thing but it will work as it is applicable for generating or getting result from database.

Comment: i have done the same.. i need the values of chart,series, xaxis, yaxis appended in json. jsonoutput is returning the required json but along with separate values of  chart,series, xaxis etc

Comment: for that you can use modified java script step, their you can write the logic, so according to your requirement use that step.